# How do I use google web fonts in coda?

Tags: macos, fonts, coda

I'm using Coda for developing my website.

I was wondering if it's possible to use google web fonts in coda so that I can test the different fonts out or even use the local fonts that are present on your machine.

What I tried doing was copy the given code but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

simply include a line like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sorts+Mill+Goudy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and then add this to your css:

```
font-family: 'Sorts Mill Goudy', serif;
```

that's it.

Comment: This works well, I have done this before, the problem is I want to test this on Coda.

When I preview this code, it gives me the default text that is present and not the one I want.

Answer (score 0):

Most font services are looking for User Agent referrer information that comes off of a typical browser. It could be that the Coda User agent string is not recognized one. Not knowing Coda well is it working off of a local web server when you preview?

Our web font service WebINK works if you configure your settings for localhost and in programs like Dreamweaver if you configure the Liveview to use localhost the fonts will show up on preview.

Google also allows you to download the fonts to your local environment. Your setup for the fonts will use standard @font-face calls in your CSS so a bit different than the

Good luck